# php access data array with foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

i've got a db table which gets filled by a submit form.

the table consists of ID, usr_ID, name, and a lot more.
i'm in the middle of making a custom table list in wordpress, and well.. i'm not the best at foreach.

how would i go about looping thru and only display each name and usr_id once when

example:

```
row 1:
id = 1, usr_id = 5, name = Alexander
row 2;
id = 2, usr_id = 4, name = james
row 3;
id = 3, usr_id = 5, name = Alexander
row 4
id = 4, usr_id = 4, name = james
```

how would i make a foreach statement that would print out:

```
usr_id = 5, name = Alexander
usr_id = 4, name = james
```

the purpose for the is to make each name clickable and then make a foreach statement only for the specific usr_id clicked on to see what has been submitted by each individual user

Comment: what is your query to do that ? is it array output or an object output ?

Comment: make `distinct` query instead of getting all rows

Answer (score 2):

> how would i make a foreach statement that would print out:

you can use this for array output:

```
foreach ($query as $v) {
    echo "usr_id = ".$v['usr_id']." , name = ".$v['name'];
}
```

you can do this too for an array output :

```
foreach ($query as $key => $list){
    echo $list['someindex'];
}
```

But I don't know if you want like that...

For complete documentation about `foreach`, please read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)... :)

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have `$array` contains your data. If `$array` is an associative array:

```
foreach($array as $a)
{
    echo "usr_id = " . $a['usr_id'] . "- name = ". $a['name'];
}
```

And if `$array` is an indexed array:

```
foreach($array as $a)
{
    echo "usr_id = " . $a[1] . "- name = ".$a[2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dbhost = 'localhost'; $dbuser = 'DB USER'; $dbpass = 'DB USER PASSWORD'; $dbname = 'DB NAME';  
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.'; dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass, array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ));

    foreach($db->query('SELECT id, usr_id, name FROM THE-TABLE WHERE id>=1') as $row) {
        $id = $row['id']; 
        $usr_id = $row['usr_id']; 
        $name = $row['name'];

        // DO WHATEVER HERE 

    }
```

or you indicated that the table had numerous columns... use a wild card

```
$dbhost = 'localhost'; $dbuser = 'DB USER'; $dbpass = 'DB USER PASSWORD'; $dbname = 'DB NAME';  
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbhost.'; dbname='.$dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass, array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ));

        foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM THE-TABLE WHERE id>=1') as $row) {
            $id = $row['id']; 
            $usr_id = $row['usr_id']; 
            $name = $row['name'];

            # the rest of the columns

            // DO WHATEVER HERE 

        }
```

Comment: i think i've been at bit unclear about my question, Alexander with usr_id 5 might have used the submit form 20 times and james with usr_id 4 might have used it 90 times how would i go about only printing each person 1 time for the purpos of making each name clickable and then list all that 1 person have submitted

Answer (score 0):

just to simplify things use

```
$name_arr=array();
foreach ($query as $v) 
{
 if(in_array($v['name'],$name_arr)==false)
   {
    $name_arr[]=$v['name'];
    echo "usr_id = ".$v['usr_id']." , name = ".$v['name'];
   }
}
```

this way each name comes only one